# Magento 2 : How to get getTireprice ,getSpecialprice and getfinalprice?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, price, tierprice, special-price

I am working in Magento 2. I need to get  `getTireprice` ,`getSpecialprice` and `getfinalprice`?

Anyone please provide same code for this.

Comment: I know how to get in Magento 1.9. How to get in Magento 2

Comment: hi @rama chandran here i have posted an answer for your question with simple test code so that you can able understand easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create a customtest.php and copy the below code and paste in the customtest.php and run it.

**Step 2:**  **customtest.php**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


//product Information 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1);
echo "Product Name ==".$product->getName()."<br>";
echo "product price ===".$product->getPrice()."<br>";
echo  "product final price ===".$product->getFinalPrice()."<br>";//
echo "product special price ===".$product->getSpecialPrice()."<br>";


getAnyGroupData($product); //custom function

function getAnyGroupData($product)
{
  $tierPrice=$product->getTierPrices();

  if(count($tierPrice) > 0)
  {
    foreach ($tierPrice as $price)
    {
        echo "Tier Price Value ==".$price->getValue()."<br>";


    }

  }

}

?>
```

**screenshots:**

[image: it shows an output]
[image: it showing admin side how we have specified]

Comment: i will check and come back :)